# Android wear 5.0.1 activity fullscreen

Tags: android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, wear-os, android-fullscreen

I have a problem since 5.0.1 update. My activity on moto 360 not taking full screen (light sensor is not part of the activity) anymore and I have now this screen :

[image: moto360 screen]

I try to add some flags :

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR);
```

Or

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN);
```

or

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMIT);
```

On my manifest :

```
        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
            android:name=".activity.DreamActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="${watchfaceName}"
            android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But no luck :( anyone have this problem ? Or even better a solution ? :) 
Of course my activity layout is set to match_parent

Comment: Having the same problem using a CardFragmentLayout, there's a default padding on the relative layout making it ugly... Still trying to figure a way to get past this problem...

Comment: It seems that there is still some issue between layout and system language in the Moto 360 LWX48P build as explained here:  https://forums.motorola.com/posts/03d71d8377?commentId=852559#852559 Maybe, your problem related to that.

Comment: I'm personnally having the issue on the Samsung Gear Live

Comment: For me I'm under LWX48T but it's not a watch face, it's a charging screen so the sensor part is on the right of the screen (activity in landscape)

Comment: Not a watchface for me too

Comment: Somebody reported me something similar in may app: https://plus.google.com/u/0/102328457713851729886/posts/KQMYavdqBjg Not sure who to deal with this.

Comment: What happens when you run the WatchViewStub sample: https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchViewStub/index.html - does it say round or square? If it says round, do you have a code sample you could share that reproduces the problem you see?

Comment: Yes it says round. I have make some test and on my manifest I have android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait" if I remove this then my layout is OK but in portrait :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution, maybe there is a better way (maybe an android wear bug ?)...

I have my basic layout and add a rotation = 90

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/main"
                android:rotation="90"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.jaumard.commonlibrary.views.DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/watchface"
        custom:onWatch="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.jaumard.commonlibrary.views.DigitalClock>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/dim"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And on my Manifest I remove the previous `android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait"`